# url alias not working when logged in as admin

Tags: path-aliases

When I'm logged in as admin, the urls are un-aliased ("node/24"). When logged out they appear aliased ("about/us"). It might have something to do with the module admin_menu as suggested in a post over at drupal.org – but applying the recommended patch didn't work for me.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1742844

Hope somebody knows a way out? Thank you! t

update: thank you for suggesting to investigate first, if it REALLY is the admin menu – and of course it's not. I switched it off, but same situation. So I guess I'll better do some further 'research' by switching off and on various recently installed modules first…

-closing-

Comment: Are you sure it's admin menu, did you try disabling admin menu module and try ?

Answer (score 1):

After dealing with this exact issue for a while in drupal 8, this thread made it click as to what the solution was.

For me, it was my choice of detection for the language that was causing the issue.

Go to /admin/config/regional/language/detection

And make sure that the only checked is the "selected language"

I had the User method checked "Follow the user's language preference." and that was what was causing the issue.

Now this might not work for a multi language site, but my site was originally in danish and I only wanted to have an english version.

Answer (score 0):

found the solution – or actually the problem:
it was my language prefs! A couple days ago I switched the admin accounts' language pref from german back to english and that made the 'german' url aliases disappear. Hope this helps somebody else someday at some point.